# SQL: multiple minimum values

Tags: mysql, sql, min

I am using mySQL and database master and I am having trouble getting the minimum value of one column for every different value of a second column.

I have a table:

```
Gene_exon (varchar), Probe_ID (Varchar) PRIMARY KEY, DISTANCE(INT), START(INT), STOP(INT).
```

There are multiple entries for each exon with the distance between this exon and different probes.

For **each exon** I'd like to find the **min distance**, and the **corresponding probe_ID,start and stop**.

I can get the correct result when I specify an exon but I want the correct result for every exon with one query!

any ideas?

thanks in advance

**edit:**
Bingo! by using group by and the below code I have managed to find what I wanted. the minimum distance per exon, which has all the correct information, :

```
SELECT gene_exon,probe_id, distance_before_EXON_START, start, stop
FROM probe_location a
WHERE distance_before_EXON_START>0 and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM probe_location B
WHERE distance_before_EXON_START>0 and A.distance_before_EXON_START>b.distance_before_EXON_START AND a.gene_exon = b.gene_exon)
GROUP BY gene_exon, probe_id, start, stop;
```

Comment: post your select for working query

Comment: try reading about `group by` in SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GROUP BY.  The trick is that every column except the one you are getting the min of is in the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT a,b,c, min(d)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY a,b,c
ORDER BY a,b,c
```